# multiple changing parameters in ODEs in R

Tags: r, ode

I have been using the deSolve function to solve ODEs and I have a Parameter, 'e', that changes throughout the code and is also used to determine some of the other bits of code. I just added another parameter r which does a similar thing throughout the code and got this warning message:

```
DLSODA-  Warning..Internal T (=R1) and H (=R2) are
      such that in the machine, T + H = T on the next step  
     (H = step size). Solver will continue anyway.
In above message, R1 = 0, R2 = 0

DINTDY-  T (=R1) illegal      
In above message, R1 = 1

      T not in interval TCUR - HU (= R1) to TCUR (=R2)      
In above message, R1 = 0, R2 = 0

DINTDY-  T (=R1) illegal      
In above message, R1 = 2

      T not in interval TCUR - HU (= R1) to TCUR (=R2)      
In above message, R1 = 0, R2 = 0

DLSODA-  Trouble in DINTDY.  ITASK = I1, TOUT = R1
In above message, I1 = 1

In above message, R1 = 2
```

my original code is:

```
parameters <- c(a = 0.32,
                b = (9/140),
                c = (5/1400),
                d = (95/700),
                k = 1/140,
                i = 0.25,
                r = 0.2,
                n = 6000000,
                x = 0.3 ,
                t = 1/180,           # important in looking at the shape
                u = 1/180,           # important in looking at the shape
                p = 10,
                s = 100,
                g = 100,

                # e = .3,
                h = 1000)
# where a is contact with infected patient
# where b is safely burried percentage
# where c is chance of being cured with no medical help
# where d is the chance that patients will go from infected to dead with no safe burial
# where e is the education percentage (percentage of patients that go into quarentine)
# where k is the chance of being cured with medical help
# where i is the infection rate (assuming contact with dead and alive ebola people are the same)
# where n is the population
# where r is the riual burial rate (unsafe contact of the dead patients with alive non infected people)
# where x is the percentage of money spent on hospitals 
# where t is how fast the education is implemented
# where m is how fast hospitals go from money to actual hospitals
# where  is the price placed on one life (the constant that is multiplied by the burrials)

state <- c(S = 5999900,
           E = 0,
           I = 100,
           Q = 1,
           D = 0,
           B = 0,
           C = 0,
           Y = 0,
           #H = 0,
           R = 1,
           #h = 100,
           e = 0
)

# where S is suseptable 
# where E is effected
# where I is infected
# where Q is quarentined
# where B is burried
# where C is cured
# where D is dead but not burried
# where Y is income
# where  is education that we have funding for
# where  is hospitals that we have funding for
# where  is education deployed
# where  is hospitals deployed 

# set up the equations 

equation <- (function(t, state, parameters) 
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
    # rate of change

    dS <- (-(a*S*I)/n) - ((r*S*D)/n)
    dE <- (a*S*I)/n + ((r*S*D)/n) - i*E
    #if (h >= Q)
    #  e = e
    #else if (h < Q )  
    #  e = 0     
    dI <- i*E - (e)*I - c*I - d*I 
    #(if (h >= Q)
    #  e = 1
    #else if (h < Q )  
    #  e = 0      
    dQ <- (e)*I - b*Q - k*Q
    dD <- d*I - r*D
    dB <- b*Q + r*D
    dC <- c*I + k*Q
    dY <- p * (b*Q + r*D)
    dR <- (1-x)* (p*(b*Q + r*D))  -t*(R) 
    de <- t*(s/R)
    #dH <- (x)* (p*(b*Q + r*D)) -u*(H)
    #dh <- u*(H/g)


    # return the rate of change
    list(c(dS, dE, dI, dQ, dD, dB, dC, dY, dR, de))
  }))
# , dH, dh 

# solve the equations for certain starting parameters


library(deSolve)
times <- seq(0, 1000, by = 1)

out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = equation, parms = parameters)
head(out)
tail(out)

# graph the results (need to know how to add D to the graph)

par(oma = c(0, 0, 3, 0))
plot(out, xlab = "Time", ylab = "People")
#plot(out[, "X"], out[, "Z"], pch = ".")
mtext(outer = TRUE, side = 3, "Ebola Model", cex = 1.5)
```

and this has been changed to:

```
parameters <- c(a = 0.32,
                b = (9/140),
                c = (5/1400),
                d = (95/700),
                k = 1/140,
                i = 0.25,
                # r = 0.2,
                n = 6000000,
                x = 0.3 ,
                t = 1/180,           # important in looking at the shape
                u = 1/180,           # important in looking at the shape
                v = 1,               # important in looking at the shape
                p = 10,
                s = 100,
                g = 100,

                    # e = .3,
                    h = 1000)
    # where a is contact with infected patient
    # where b is safely burried percentage
    # where c is chance of being cured with no medical help
    # where d is the chance that patients will go from infected to dead with no safe burial
    # where e is the education percentage (percentage of patients that go into quarentine)
    # where k is the chance of being cured with medical help
    # where i is the infection rate (assuming contact with dead and alive ebola people are the same)
    # where n is the population
    # where r is the riual burial rate (unsafe contact of the dead patients with alive non infected people)
    # where x is the percentage of money spent on hospitals 
    # where t is how fast the education is implemented
    # where m is how fast hospitals go from money to actual hospitals
    # where  is the price placed on one life (the constant that is multiplied by the burrials)

    state <- c(S = 5999900,
               E = 0,
               I = 100,
               Q = 1,
               D = 0,
               B = 0,
               C = 0,
               Y = 0,
               #H = 0,
               R = 1,
               J =0,
               #h = 100,
               e = 0.3,
               r = 0.3 
    )

    # where S is suseptable 
    # where E is effected
    # where I is infected
    # where Q is quarentined
    # where B is burried
    # where C is cured
    # where D is dead but not burried
    # where Y is income
    # where  is education that we have funding for
    # where  is hospitals that we have funding for
    # where  is education deployed
    # where  is hospitals deployed 

    # set up the equations 

    equation <- (function(t, state, parameters) 
      with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
        # rate of change

        dS <- (-(a*S*I)/n) - ((r*S*D)/n)
        dE <- (a*S*I)/n + ((r*S*D)/n) - i*E
        #if (h >= Q)
        #  e = e
        #else if (h < Q )  
        #  e = 0     
        dI <- i*E - (e)*I - c*I - d*I 
        #(if (h >= Q)
        #  e = 1
        #else if (h < Q )  
        #  e = 0      
        dQ <- (e)*I - b*Q - k*Q
        dD <- d*I - r*D
        dB <- b*Q + r*D
        dC <- c*I + k*Q
        dY <- p * (b*Q + r*D)
        dR <- (1-x)* (p*(b*Q + r*D))  -t*(R) 
        de <- t*(s/R)
        dJ <- (x)* (p*(b*Q + r*D))  -v*(J)
        dr <- v*(s/J)
        #dH <- (x)* (p*(b*Q + r*D)) -u*(H)
        #dh <- u*(H/g)


        # return the rate of change
        list(c(dS, dE, dI, dQ, dD, dB, dC, dY, dR, de, dJ, dr))
      }))
    # , dH, dh 

    # solve the equations for certain starting parameters


    library(deSolve)
    times <- seq(0, 100, by = 1)

    out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = equation, parms = parameters)
    head(out)
    tail(out)

    # graph the results (need to know how to add D to the graph)

    par(oma = c(0, 0, 3, 0))
    plot(out, xlab = "Time", ylab = "People")
    #plot(out[, "X"], out[, "Z"], pch = ".")
    mtext(outer = TRUE, side = 3, "Ebola Model", cex = 1.5)
```

any help would be great!

Comment: It looks like the required time step is smaller than machine precision. Does this problem persist when you use other methods? For example `out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = equation, parms = parameters, method = "vode")`. Also, I wonder if reducing the requested precision by changing `atol` and `rtol` would help.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Lyngbakr, got it now

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: I changed some of the starting states to larger numbers, it was taking too many steps to make it change in a meaningful way. Thanks for your help!